# Match up SKU with SKU variation

Tags: csv, magento

Firstly, good luck with this one lol. I'm sure there's a way of doing this, but for the life of me i can't even think of how to word it.

So, here goes: speaking in e-commerce terms, i have a list of products with their SKU (a unique code to distinguish it), and a list of product sizes. We are using Magento, so each product has a Main product, and you link each variation to that main product. (configurable and simple products for Magento techies)

Here's an example using SKU's:

A1000B - main product

A1000SB - size small

A1000MB - size medium

A1000LB - size large

A1000XLB - size xl

A1000 is the part no., S being Small, and B being Black.

SKU's end in either a number or letter.

SKU's are identical up until the size and colour.

SKU's are varying sizes.

I need to somehow match up the sizes to the main product.

The only way i see this working for all SKU's would be a partial vlookup of sorts. I have tried the approximate match vlookup (adding true instead of false) however this doesn't work as the SKU's are so similar.

I am completely lost on this. Any advice or help with this would be amazing and highly appreciated.

Thanks,
D

Comment: I'm guessing by your reference to vlookup you are hoping to achieve this and a spreadsheet?

Comment: Sorry yes, I am working from 2 spreadsheets, one with main products and one with just the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% is this is the kind of thing you're looking for but you could potentially use excel `SUBSTITUTE` on the SKU to remove the size data then use that 'main product' to filter your SKUs by.

In the below image I've created a basic data set which might look like a simplified version of your SKU data. In the `Helper Col` I've added a function which essentially just removes the size characters of the SKU, I've done this using nested `SUBSTITUTE` statements which aren't the neatest looking things in the world but should do the trick.

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A14,"XLB",""),"LB",""),"MB",""),"SB",""),"B","")`

Each `SUBSTITUTE` is essentially doing a find and replace of the keyword in that cell and replacing it with a blank "". The order is important because you want to replace `XLB` first because if you tried to match just `B` first you'd end up with some cells showing `A100XL`.

It wasn't clear in the question if you wanted to keep the `B` or not, as you talk about both the 'main product' and also the 'part number'. However using more nested statements you could keep the `B` by replacing it back in instead of a "".

You could then use this column to filter by your products and see all the appropriate SKUs

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Jonny, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, the SKUs can vary in length, and can also start with 2 letters instead of 1. This means any sort of blanket method to reduce the size, or pull a section of the code wouldn't work for them all :(.